# Context switch by random system call

Tags: operating-system, kernel, system

I know that an interrupt causes the OS to change a CPU from its current task and to run a kernel routine.  I this case, the system has to save the current context of the process running on the CPU.
However, I would like to know whether or not a context switch occurs when any random process makes a system call.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know whether or not a context switch occurs when any random process makes a system call.

Not precisely. Recall that a process can only make a system call if it's currently running -- there's no need to make a context switch to a process that's already running.

If a process makes a blocking system call (e.g, `sleep()`), there will be a context switch to the next runnable process, since the current process is now sleeping. But that's another matter.

Comment: Could you tell me what the role of "process control block" is in this process?

Comment: what about read file , doesn't current process give up cpu core ?

Answer (score 0):

There are generally 2 ways to cause a content switch. (1) a timer interrupt invokes the scheduler that forcibly makes a context switch or (2) the process yields. Most operating systems have a number of system services that will cause the process to yield the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

well I got your point. so, first I clear a very basic idea about system call.
when a process/program makes a syscall and interrupt the kernel to invoke syscall handler. TSS loads up Kernel stack and jump to syscall function table.
See It's actually same as running a different part of that program itself, the only major change is Kernel play a role here and that piece of code will be executed in ring 0.

now your question "**what will happen if a context switch happen when a random process is making a syscall?**"

well, nothing will happen. Things will work in same way as they were working earlier. Just instead of having normal address in TSS you will have address pointing to Kernel stack and SysCall function table address in that random process's TSS.